# Concatenate several awk command outputs in one command

Tags: parsing, awk

**I have an input like as follows with many, many rows, and I need to parse all this file into a better format, could be a CSV file or JSON (maybe in the future). 
So I need to produce an outcome with columns delimited by a comma, thinking of being able to export the content in CSV file for now.

Get the name files

`awk '{ if($2 ~ /A/ ) print $1 }' dir_out`

Get all the paths

```
awt ' /[\\]/ {print}'
```

Get the size of the files

```
awk '{ if($3 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $3}'
```

Right now I have the individual commands to generate the desired result, however I have to find a way to put them in the same line of awk commands, or in a script.

One of the critical points that I have not been able to solve is to make column 1 of the outcome the path that delimits each block, for all the files in the block.

So I starting from this input:
**

```
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl
 R0097A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  6958377  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2794933  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1350397  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A+11.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  6997803  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A+11.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2783151  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A+11.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1338662  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A-00.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  7069740  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A-00.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2825705  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 R0097A-00.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1369520  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
 Jhumbs.db                           A    20480  Fri Jun  8 13:14:41 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl
 R0098A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  6958377  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2794933  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A+05.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1350398  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A+11.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  6998803  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A+11.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2783151  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A+11.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1338662  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A-00.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  7069840  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A-00.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2825705  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 R0098A-00.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1369520  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
 Jhumbs.db                           A    20480  Fri Jun  8 13:14:41 2018`
```

ljkhlj

```
     PATH, FILENAME, SIZE, TIMESTAMP
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl,    R0097A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6958377,  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2794933, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018 
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 1350397, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl,  R0097A+11.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6997803, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6958377, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 6958377, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+05.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 6958377, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
     \QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+11.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6958377, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of combining your awk command into a single script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
$2 ~ /A/  {print $1; }  
/[\\]/    {print}
$3 ~ /^[0-9]/ {print $3}
' "$@"
```

In general, awk takes multiple  /search/ {command} pairs.  If /search/ is missing, it defaults to all lines and if {command} is missing, it defaults to print.

Here's the additional logic you need to get your expected results:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v OFS=, '
BEGIN { print "PATH, FILENAME, SIZE, TIMESTAMP" }
/[\\]/    { path=$0 }
$2 ~ /A/  {print path,$1,$3,$4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 }  
' "$@"
```

Comment: This prints three lines, not one line with three fields.

Comment: Also, `$*` should be `"$@"`

Comment: Indeed, "$@" is way more important on a windows box where spaces in file names is quite common.  It's also the right way to go in Linux land, too.  I've made the change to the code.

Comment: The updated script flattens the spaces in the date stamp; maybe use `printf` if fixed-width formatting in important (or perhaps properly parse the dates into machine-readable format).

Comment: Tangentially, `\\ ` doesn't really need to be in a character class.

Comment: And would be the right approach if one of the images has a spaces on it? One of my thoughts is to read it backwords, with this command I can get the images name with spaces: awk -v FS='\t' '{print $1}' but I don't know how to integrate it to you approach

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ", "
    print "PATH", "FILENAME", "SIZE", "TIMESTAMP"
}
/^ / {
    file = $1
    size = $3
    sub(/^ ([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}/,"")
    print path, file, size, $0
    next
}
{ path = $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
PATH, FILENAME, SIZE, TIMESTAMP
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6958377, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2794933, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 1350397, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+11.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6997803, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+11.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2783151, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A+11.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 1338662, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A-00.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 7069740, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A-00.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2825705, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, R0097A-00.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 1369520, Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl, Jhumbs.db, 20480, Fri Jun  8 13:14:41 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6958377, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2794933, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+05.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 1350398, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+11.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 6998803, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+11.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2783151, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A+11.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 1338662, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A-00.00B-00-QingL.JPG, 7069840, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A-00.00B-00-QingLI.JPG, 2825705, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, R0098A-00.00B-00-QingLO.JPG, 1369520, Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
\QJ DaJabase EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl, Jhumbs.db, 20480, Fri Jun  8 13:14:41 2018
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, another thing; would be the right approach if one of the image name has a spaces on it? One of my thoughts is to read it backwords, with this command I can get the images name with spaces: awk -v FS='\t' '{print $1}' but I don't know how to integrate it to you approach

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to revisit a question from a month ago now.